# Collision through for loop

Tags: c#, xna

```
    for (int x = bulletBounds.Count - 1; x > -1; x-- )
        {
            for (int y = alienPosition.Count - 1; y > -1; y--)
            {
                if (bulletBounds[x].Intersects(alienBounds[y]))
                {
                    alienPosition.RemoveAt(y);
                    bulletBounds.RemoveAt(x);
                    hit++;
                }
            }
        }
```

What I'm trying to do with this code is go through both lists of objects and see if they collide. I saw in another question that the only way to do this is iterate backwards through the list so I did that. The issue now is that when a bullet collides with an alien, every alien before it in the list is also getting deleted. So if I have 6 aliens on the screen and I hit the one on the far left, every alien to the right of it gets deleted! How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Just put a breakpoint on the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the alien and bullet you need to break out of the inner loop.

```
 if (bulletBounds[x].Intersects(alienBounds[y]))
 {
     alienPosition.RemoveAt(y);
     alienBounds.RemoveAt(y);
     bulletBounds.RemoveAt(x);
     hit++;
     break;
 }
```

Comment: Try removing the entry from alienBounds also.

Answer (score 0):

Add `break;` to your if loop. By the way, what's the difference between alienBounds and alienPosition? You're looping through alienPosition, however, accessing data in alienBounds. In the example below, I'm just looping through alienBounds. If I misunderstood anything, please let me know, and I will update my answer accordingly.

```
foreach (var bullet in bulletBounds)
{
    foreach (var alien in alienBounds)
    {
        if (bullet.Intersects(alien))
        {
            bulletBounds.Remove(bullet);
            alienBounds.Remove(alien);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have two lists for the alien, alienPosition creates the position and draws the alien, while alienBounds creates the rectangle around the alien created in alienPosition. I also have the same method for my bullet lists. I know this is not the best way to do this but I couldnt think of another alternative

Comment: This will not work.  You can not iterate (foreach) a collection/array/list and remove at the same time.